# writing a program to act like command line in C

Tags: c, unix

So from what I found out on my own I know I'm going to need to use `fork()` and `execvp()`, but I can't quite figure out how to use `execvp()` correctly from any examples online. Its supposed to let me essentially run command line stuff, but I don't understand the arguments it takes. Like if I wanted to run `ls -a` how would I put that into `execvp()`? And then there's the problem of `exec()` doesn't return. How do I handle that?

Answer (score 3):

First, `exec()` doesn't return because it results in the process having it executing program replaced with whatever program was `exec()`ed. That is if you run `ls` via `exec()` after a `fork()` the PID of `ls` will be the same as the one that called `exec()`. That is `exec()` doesn't create a new process so it can't return because all the memory and code from the program that called it is effectively gone and replaced with whatever it `exec()`ed

Run `ls -a` with `execvp()` assuming `ls` is in `/bin`

```
const char *file = "/bin/ls";
const char *arg1 = "ls";
const char *arg2 = "-a";
const char **argv = {arg1, arg2, NULL};
execvp(file, argv);
```

Comment: Note: The return value of `execvp()` should be returned from `main()`.

Comment: @chux What? Are you talking about the fact that I didn't include any error handling? Unless `execvp()` fails it simply doesn't return at all, that's it. The parent process will be able to get the exit value of the `exec()`d program no matter what we do with the return value since if it succeeds it doesn't return. Error handling wise we can do whatever we want and return whatever exit code we choose. Or we could use IPC of some kind to tell our parent we failed, what ever.

Comment: Good answer, however, *I* would fork() and if child then call execvp().  Then the parent process could call waitpid() so it resumes running after the child process exits.    Also, want to parse the user entered input rather than hard coding the single 'ls' command

Comment: @user3629249 I was just showing how `execvp()` works not trying to solve the whole thing since that's really what the question was about.

Comment: @Spudd86 so `*file` will always be "/bin/<command>"? and why add `NULL` to the `argv`? the rest I think I understand

Comment: @TommyK The `NULL` is how `execvp()` knows where the end of the argument list is, it must be there